# MySQL Function SEC_TO_TIME not working in UPDATE clause

Tags: mysql

Some of my columns have duration values for company phone calls, in which the duration is stored in seconds. I wanted to convert these values to a DD:HH:MM:SS format, and I intended to use MySQL's `Sec_to_Time` function, which worked well when used in a `SELECT` statement, in an `UPDATE` statement in order to convert the seconds values to DD:HH:MM:SS values permanently.

However, I tried it on a couple tables with an `UPDATE` command, but the update either multiplied the value in the column (ex.: 19212 changed to ~32000) or truncated the column.

So I tried the following code, just to see what was happening.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE QueueTime_Snapshot (QueueTime int);

INSERT INTO QueueTime_Snapshot (Queuetime)
SELECT QueueTime FROM CDB_Call_and_Agent_Data;

UPDATE QueueTime_Snapshot
SET QueueTime = SEC_TO_TIME(QueueTime);

SELECT QueueTime FROM QueueTime_Snapshot;
```

The SELECT statement returned the exact values that I had inserted into the temp table; nothing had changed (which is strange, since the other two update statements had effected massive changes to the data). When I executed

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(QueueTime) FROM QueueTime_Snapshot;
```

I received the expected values, converted to the format I had wanted. Is this function (or are functions in general) simply not allowed to be used in an UPDATE statement, or is there another reason the values aren't being converted in the way I want them to be?

Comment: Can you share the exact code, along with table definition(s) you used when it was not working as expected?

Comment: `UPDATE AgentSummaryTable SET total_logged_in_time = SEC_TO_TIME(total_logged_in_time)`

was the code I tried, which failed. The table definition is as follows:

total_logged_in_time int(25)
total_not_ready int(25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are storing a `time` datatype value as an int? It seems you are running into data conversion issues.

```
UPDATE AgentSummaryTable SET total_logged_in_time = SEC_TO_TIME(total_logged_in_time)
```

That statement is converting 1 datatype (int, datatype of the column) into another datatype (time) and then storing in back into an int. Generally, you should avoid attempting to store multiple data types into one data type.

If you plan on having a `int` column, you should store the time values in seconds, and convert to a `time` value as needed. Otherwise, store your time values as a `time` column. The time value `05:20:12` converted to an int results in `052012` which is certainly not the seconds of that time. The functions `TIME_TO_SEC` and `SEC_TO_TIME` should be used to convert from time to seconds and vice versa.

Consider:

```
create table t(t int);
insert into t values (sec_to_time(19212));

select sec_to_time(19212),
       cast(sec_to_time(19212) as unsigned integer) i,
       sec_to_time(19212) + 0 s,
       t,
       sec_to_time(t)
from   t;
```

The actual results may vary across versions, but notice the difference in values.